# htaccess redirects for usernames in URL while ignoring directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got a complicated .htaccess redirect issue. I am trying to redirect legacy site affiliates to a second domain, where the structure can be the following:

1. username.domain.com redirects to seconddomain.com/username
2. domain.com/username redirects to seconddomain.com/username
3. www.domain.com needs to redirect to domain.com, not secondomain.com/www
4. domain.com and subdirectories (i.e. css, js, img) don't get redirected

Below is my current .htaccess however it is incorrectly redirecting www.domain.com to seconddomain.com/www and incorrectly redirecting links to js, css, and img directories to the seconddomain as well:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seconddomain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seconddomain.com/%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://seconddomain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Here, take my upvote (throwing upvote)...one of the few VERY clear and well structured apache rewrite questions :) will work on your solution as soon as I got time for it :D

Comment: question: How can you distinguish between username and subdirectories? Because I got your solution except the last part where domain.com/username and domain.com/css,js,etc. should be distinguished :/

Comment: I don't think I can distinguish between usernames and subdirectories because there are potentially thousands of usernames. I can set a finite number of directories however. So if I set a finite group of directories can I somehow ignore those directories while not ignoring anything that doesn't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You had four cases listed:**

1. username.example.com redirects to secondexample.com/username
2. example.com/username redirects to secondexample.com/username
3. www.example.com needs to redirect to example.com, not
   secondexample.com/www
4. example.com and subdirectories (i.e. css, js, img) don't get
   redirected

**The following should handle those cases:**

```
RewriteEngine on

#should handle case 3) www.example.com needs to redirect to example.com, not secondexample.com/www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,END]

#should handle case 1) username.example.com redirects to secondexample.com/username
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secondexample.com/%1/ [R=301,L]

#should handle case 2) example.com/username redirects to secondexample.com/username
#and 4) example.com and subdirectories (i.e. css, js, img) don't get redirected
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|js|img|<add-more-if-needed>)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secondexample.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've swapped out my code to test your code above. Now, however, rule #3 is redirecting www.domain.com to domain.com which is then redirecting to seconddomain.com. I think we need one additional rule so that domain.com on its own doesn't redirect to seconddomain.com.

Comment: The rule to ignore subdirectories that I specify works perfectly.

Comment: Since I can choose to ignore a specific subdirectory (i.e. css), for my purposes I can redirect www.domain.com to domain.com/subdir/ without impacting my users. I'm struggling to get domain.com to redirect to domain.com/subdir/, it keeps getting redirected to seconddomain.com due to rule #1 I believe.

Comment: for what it's worth, I am not able to use a user subdirectory because of a legacy architecture. I've posted an adaptation above with the latest code that I am attempting. (note: my lexicon changed from domain.com to example.com so I could post). Now, www.example.com redirects to example.com/test but example.com (without www) redirects to secondexample.com.

Comment: I shortened my answer accordingly and exchanged the `[L]` for `[END]` I am not 100% sure the last `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` works as expected, but plz try my updated code and let me know how it went ;)

Comment: I updated with your latest code however the [R=301,END] was causing an internal server error. So I reverted it that part back to [R=301,L] and now everything works as I hoped! 

Thank you so much @Hello Fishy!

Comment: you are very welcome :) and thatnks for the feedback as well :)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I've got now. Everything works except for example.com is redirecting to secondexample.com. www.example.com actually redirects to example.com/test/ which works because i've added test to my ignored subdirectories.

```
RewriteEngine on

#should handle case 3) www.example.com needs to redirect to example.com, not 
#secondexample.com/www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/test/$1/ [R=301,L]

#should handle case 1) username.example.com redirects to 
#secondexample.com/username
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secondexample.com/%1/ [R=301,L]

#should handle case 2) example.com/username redirects to 
#secondexample.com/username
#and 4) example.com and subdirectories (i.e. css, js, img) don't get 
#redirected
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|scripts|img|video)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secondexample.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```